# Existence of infinitely many sequences of this kind that are prime-free

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there exists infinitely many positive integers, $x$, such that the sequence $(a_n)$: $$a_0=1, a_1=x+1, a_{n+2}=xa_{n+1}-a_n$$ is prime-free (i.e. all terms are composite).

Note: observe that $a_{4n}\equiv a_{4n+1}\equiv 1  ~(mod ~p)$ and $a_{4n+2}\equiv a_{4n+3}\equiv x-1  ~(mod ~p)$, I guess terms in this sequence that share a common prime factor of $x\pm1$ have their positions repeat in a periodic pattern.

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: Won't help much probably, but $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-\lfloor (k+1)/2 \rfloor}{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} (-1)^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}x^{n-k}$

Comment: This is from a past local math Olympiad exam, looks like a 'delicately designed' problem.

Comment: Yes, Sil. The two characteristic roots of the recurrence relation are $\xi_{1,2}=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2},$ that allows one to write down a general form for $a_n$ as linear combination of $\xi_1^n$ and $\xi_2^n$. But it's difficult to work with surds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polynomials that never produce primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705913/polynomials-that-never-produce-primes)