# Polynomials that never produce primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This problem was given to me by an acquaintance during a basketball game.

> Define the sequence $a_n$ as follows: $$a_0=1, a_1=x+1, a_{n+2}=xa_{n+1}-a_n$$ Prove that there exists
> infinitely many positive integers $x$ such that $a_n$ is never a
> prime.

This looks like a very interesting problem, but I haven’t made any progress at all. The only thing I have in regards is that the polynomials $T_n(\frac{x}2)$ satisfy the same recurrence relation, but do not have the same initial values. I think the problem should be true for any recurrent sequence of polynomials, but I cannot prove this. When I first read the problem, two well known theorems popped up in my mind: for a finite family of polynomials, there is a value at which they all assume a composite number, and any recurrent sequence is periodic modulo any number. So if we take $a_1, \cdots a_s$, and assure that $a_i$ is composite and divisible by a prime $p_i$. And if we let the periods of $a_n$ mod $p_i$ be $m_i$. If we can assure somehow that: $\text{lcm}(m_1,\cdots,m_s)\le s$, then we’d be done

The source is: Korea Final Round $2019/3$. The solution isn’t that hard and is motivated by the fact that: $a_na_{n+2}=a_{n+1}^2-(x+2).$

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_0%3D1%2Ca_1%3Dx%2B1%2Ca_%7Bn%2B2%7D%3Dxa_%7Bn%2B1%7D-a_n%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integers&p=1), there's [Existence of infinitely many sequences of this kind that are prime-free](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728546), but with it currently not having any answer.

Comment: Have you found a single $x$ which at least appears to work?

Comment: @lulu $x=7$ seems to be working

Comment: True...and the factoring of each term looks entirely random.

Comment: Just found the source, and it’s Korea Final Round 2019/3. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1808432p12035617

Comment: When $7\le x\equiv 2 \pmod 5$ we have   $5 \,|\,a_2=x^2+x-1=((2x+1)^2-5)/4>5.$

Comment: @ZNatox It's great you found the source, and also that the AoPS thread [Prime-free sequence](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1808432p12035617) has a valid solution. Please consider answering your own question with a detailed solution. I could then also vote to close the other question here I found, i.e., [Existence of infinitely many sequences of this kind that are prime-free](/q/3728546), as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Semiclassical $551=19\cdot29$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the AOPS answer. The formula $a_na_{n+2}=a_{n+1}^2-(x+2)$, which is a consequence of $\frac{a_{n+2}+a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ being constant motivates taking $x+2=a^2$. Now: $a_na_{n+2}=(a_{n+1}-a)(a_{n+1}+a)$ If we can ensure that: $a_{n+2}>a_{n+1}+a$ then we’d be done, but it can be easily seen that this must be true. $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=(x-2)a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}-a_n>a_{n+1}-a_n>a_1-a_0=a^2-2>a$